# How to find count from two joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have to find count for each risk category for impact level as shown in last result part

Risk Table

```
RiskID  RiskName
----------------------

1   Risk1
2   Risk2
3   Risk3
4   Risk4
5   Risk5
6   Risk6
7   Risk7
8   Risk8
9   Risk9
10  Risk10
11  Risk11
```

Category Table

```
Cat_ID  Cat_Name
--------------------------

1   Design
2   Operation
3   Technical
```

Risk_Category table

```
Risk_ID     Category_ID
------------------------

1       1
1       2
2       1
3       1
3       3
4       1
5       2
6       1
7       3
8       1
9       3
10      3
```

Risk_Impact_Assessment table

```
Risk_ID     Impact_Level    Impact_Score
---------------------------------------------

1       High        20  
2       Medium      15  
3       High        20
4       Low     10
5       High        20
6       High        20
7       High        20
8       Low     10
9       Medium      15
10      Low     15
11      Medium      15
```

Result should be like this

```
Cat_Name    Impact_Level_High   Impact_Level_Medium Impact_Level_Low
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Design          1           1           2                               
Operation       2                                                   
Technical       2               2           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `group by` clause, along with `case`, eg.:

```
select
 Cat_Name, 
 sum(case when Impact_Level = 'High' then 1 else 0 end) as [Impact_Level_High],
 sum(case when Impact_Level = 'Medium' then 1 else 0 end) as [Impact_Level_Medium],
 sum(case when Impact_Level = 'Low' then 1 else 0 end) as [Impact_Level_Low]
from [Risk_Impact_Assessment]
...
group by Cat_Name;
```

(I left out all the joins, I assume you can write these no problem)

You can use this trick to accomplish a lot of cool things, including parametric sorting and (just like here) complicated aggregate functions with little work.

Comment: Thanks Luaan for your prompt help